# Eloquent JavaScript: The Lycanthrope's Log, table values?

Tags: javascript

I am working on eloquent javascript at the lycanthrope's log, I can't seem to understand, I've been checking values and testing on console.log but I cant seem to get this code:

```
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  // ...
]

function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1; // check if event occured / not  false
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
   var entry = journal[i], index = 0;

   if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1; // if pizza occured, add+1 on table index
    //object of arrays --> console.log(entry); 
   if (entry.squirrel) index += 2; // if squirrel is true, add+2 on index
   table[index] += 1; //<-- I don't understand this 
   // console.log(index);
  }
 return table;
}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
// I don't understand how values are added here, 
// how did this become→ [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

How are values added on indexes? please help me understand this program.

Comment: have you added the contents of the `JOURNAL` variable?

Comment: yes, I just can't understand this code

Answer (score 0):

If we analyze each `item` of the `JOURNAL` collection the indexes of the table represent the following:

- `table[0]` gets +1 if the event doesn't exist in `item.events` and `squirrel: false`
- `table[1]` gets +1 if the event exists in `item.events` and `squirrel: false`
- `table[2]` gets +1 if the event doesn't exist in `item.events` and `squirrel: true`
- `table[3]` gets +1 if the event exists in `item.events` and `squirrel: true`

As you see it's just a table that keeps track of the various combinations of the two variables observed (squirrel and pizza), the table is finally fed to the function `phi` which computes the correlation between the variables

Note that if you used the formula he provided for phi perhaps it would've been easier to make the table a 2x2 matrix i.e. have `table[0][0], table[0][1], table[1][0] and table[1][1]` where rows meant the state of the squirrel and columns the existence of pizza in `item.events`

Comment: can you please tell me where/how did it happen in the code?

Answer (score 0):

From the original Eloquent Javascript explanation, the journal/log contains about 90 entries `JOURNAL.length`

```
function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];

//Here we declare a table with 4 figures that will be incremented,
```

```
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
   var entry = journal[i], index = 0;

//Next we initiate a loop for journal.length
```

Remember `JOURNAL.length = 90`, so this loop will run 90 times.

The first time this loop will run `i = 0` , so `journal[i] = {"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false}`, `index = 0` and we are testing for `"pizza"`

```
if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1; 

//when journal[i] meets this if statement, if(hasEvent(event, entry)) returns False, so index = 0
```

```
if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;

//journal[i] moves to this if statement, entry.squirrel returns False,
//hence index is not incremented by 2, index is still 0.

//NOTE: the increment is done to the 'index' variable not 'table index'.
```

```
//before the code below index = 0 still (for journal[i] where i=0)
//remember this is the first iteration (i=0) so table is still [0,0,0,0]

 table[index] += 1; 

//table[index] is the same as table[0] and table[0] = 0,
//hence table[index] = table[index] + 1 is the same as table[index]= 0+1.
//table[index] += 0 where index = 0 ==== goto the first item i the table array and add 1 to it.

//at this point table = [1, 0, 0, 0] but the loop will run 89 more times.
  }

//when the loop is finally complete, table = [76, 9, 4, 1]
 return table;
}
```

For the code you posted,
`JOURNAL` only has 3 entries hence
`console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL))` Outputs: table = [3, 0, 0, 0];